# Algotrading - store websocket data in database

Tags: database, sqlite, websocket, redis, stockquotes

I'm trying with Algo-trading. so I have WebSocket which has market data, I'm trying to store in the database. other modules read this stored database and make the buy/sell decisions.

1. what should be the best database option here considering it should be faster to insert the data and required concurrent reading.
2. how do I handle the WebSocket data, it contains a lot of data to store, without losing the data.

?

Answer (score 2):

To answer question 1:

You can use a memory based database such as redis.

For question 2:
you can use rabbitMQ or kafka.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1:

Several people use [Redis Timeseries](https://oss.redis.com/redistimeseries/) to store market data for analysis/display.  Insert and retreival are fast.

For question 2:

You could run several consumers and use Redis for de-duplication so you don't update everything twice, but it will heavily depend on your stack

Comment: is redis really faster than sqllite 3?

Comment: It will depend on the queries you are doing.  However, Redis really shines in your use case if more than 1 node will be accessing the data at a given time, will be easier to HA if required and easier to backup and restore.